Average cluster size of a n-size vector
Given a vector of $n$ cells and $k$ elements in it, we can define a cluster of elements as a contiguous sequence of elements inside the vector.
My goal is to calculate the average cluster size for all possible values of $k$. For example, if $k=1$ the average cluster size is 1, since all the possible arrangements of 1 element in the vector are made up of 1 element: $\text{w1}(n)\text{=}1$
When there are 2 elements in the vector, we have more possibilities:
$\text{w2}(n)\text{=}\frac{2 \binom{n}{2}}{2 (\binom{n}{2}-(n-1))+(n-1)}=\frac{n}{n-1}$
First, there are $(n-2)$ arrangements with a cluster of size 2, then, the rest of the possible arrangements have a cluster size of 1, since they are separated along the vector cells.
For 3 elements:
$\text{w3}(n)\text{=}\frac{3 \binom{n}{3}}{3 (\binom{n}{3}-(n-2)-((n-4) (n-3)+2 (n-3)))+(n-2)+2 ((n-4) (n-3)+2 (n-3))}=\frac{n}{n-2}$
First, there are $(n-2)$ arrangements for the cluster of size 3, $(n-1) (n-2)$ arrangements for the cluster of size 2 and the remaining element, which globally counts as a $3/2$ size cluster. And finally, the remaining arrangements are reserved for the cases when all the 3 elements are separated, counting as a cluster size of 1.
So far I have only reached $w3(n)$, but my goal is to create a general formula $cs(n,k)$ which returns the average cluster size for a specific value of $n$ and $k$.

It isn't too hard to calculate the expected number of clusters, but what you want is the expected reciprocal of this number (times $k$), which seems quite a lot harder to calculate

You can probably express this as a sum over the $2^{k-1}$ ordered partitions of $k$. Would this be good enough?

@daniel-weber Perhaps. What I actually need is a way to express the expected cluster size for a vector of size $n$ with $k$ elements inside, considering all possible arrangements of all amounts of elements between $1$ and $k$.

The average cluster size is surely the total cluster size divided by the number of clusters, so the numerator is $k \binom{n}{k}$. Your $w2$ and $w3$ appear to have the binomial in the denominator instead. Are you sure they're correct?

With $k=2$, $n=3$ there are three possible vectors: two have a cluster of size $2$ and one has two clusters of size $1$. That gives an average cluster size of $\frac{6}{4} \neq \frac{4}{3}+(1-\frac{2}{3})$

@peter-taylor I have just corrected both expressions, together with their simplifications.

@peter-taylor Perhaps the solution is of the form $\frac{n}{n-k+1}$??

Empirically that checks out. Haven't found a proof yet. It's equivalent to the average number of clusters over all $\binom{n}{k}$ vectors being $k - \frac{k(k-1)}{n}$, which might be a sensible proof goal.

It is $\frac{n}{n-k+1}$ as you suggest. Here is a proof by recursion.
Let $b_{n,k}$ be the cumulative number of clusters of digits one's in binary words (your vectors) with length $n$ and $k$ one's (your elements). Then
$$b_{n,k}=\begin{cases} 0&\quad\text{if }\;k\le 0\;\text{ or }\;n\lt k\\ n&\quad\text{if }\;k=1\le n\end{cases}$$
and
$$b_{n+1,k+1} = b_{n,k+1}+b_{n,k}+\binom{n-1}{k}\qquad\text{if }\;0\le k\;\text{ and }\;1\le n$$
because the clusters of binary words with length $n+1$ starting with a zero are the clusters of words with length $n$ and the same
digits one's, shifted. Hence their number is $b_{n,k+1}$. And the clusters of the other binary words with length $n+1$ starting with a one are those of words with length $n$, with their first cluster lengthened when they too start with a one, or with an additional cluster when they start with a zero, adding $\binom{n-1}{k}$ clusters (of size $1$) to $b_{n,k}$ clusters.
Now one can easily check that
$$b_{n,k}=(n-k+1)\binom{n-1}{k-1}\; [0<k\le n]$$
satisfies those conditions, where $[\cdot]$ is the Iverson bracket, yielding
$$\frac{k\binom{n}{k}}{b_{n,k}} = \frac{n}{n-k+1}.$$

Thanks for the proof. Is there a similar formula for $n\times n$ matrices? Or at least an expression to get the total number of clusters?
